# Calculate Average for MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to calculate an average for a MultiIndex DataFrame based on the number of rows at that level.

[Image of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzcTv.png)

Basically, I have to average values in the last column by summing those and dividing by the number of rows in Month for each `SKU_ID` index. How do I proceed in Pandas?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Also in sample is no `ORDERITEM_QTY_SKU` level

Comment: @jezrael Edited for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In just the same way as you would without the MultiIndex.

`df.groupby('month').mean()`

Comment: The question notes that there is grouping by `SKU_ID` and implies that a multiindex has to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

An MCVE was not provided, so the question cannot be precisely answered.

Following is an example showing grouping on a multiindex calculating a statistic of certain data.   And then joining the results so that further manipulation of a statistic can be done.

Providing an answer in the context of what is an MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Customer ID,SKU,Month,Value
C00005,550000,4,16
C00005,560000,5,17
C00005,560000,5,13
C00005,570000,6,18
C00005,570000,6,16
C00005,570000,6,15
C00005,560000,4,18
C00004,570000,5,17
C00004,570000,5,14
C00004,560000,6,16""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", index_col=["Customer ID", "SKU", "Month"])

# Get count of month rows for each group
grouped_month_count = df.groupby(['Customer ID', 'SKU', 'Month']).count()
grouped_month_count.columns = ['Month Count']

# get sum of values for each group
summed_values = df.groupby(['Customer ID', 'SKU', 'Month']).sum()
summed_values.columns = ['Value Sum']

result = grouped_month_count.join(summed_values)
result['Average'] = result['Value Sum']/result['Month Count']
print(result)
```